# Chrome 105.0.5195.102 breaks PHP YII application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, yii2

Google rolled out an emergency security fix and now some of the JS behavior is not working as it was before. Anybody else having this problem?

This is one of the functions that is not working like it did before.  It disables the button but the form is never submitted.

```html
function disableButton(elButton) {
    let elForm = elButton.closest(':has(\"form\")').find('form:visible');
    elForm.on('afterValidate', function(e) {
        let errors = elForm.find('.has-error').length;
        if (errors>0) elButton.attr('disabled', false);
    });
    elButton.attr('disabled', true);
    elForm.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this function and it's work. This form is yii2 ActiveForm. My Chrome version: Version 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (x86_64) (OSX)

[image: I try]